Ubuntu 24.04 upgrade. does it work with ZFS?
I know this is an old question but i'm in a particular use case.
Canonical now has a history of being inconstant with whether they like or hate ZFS.
I personally love ZFS and don't want to loose my bootability (my OS is currently 23.10 with ZFS on Root)
if ZFS on root aren't within ubuntu 24's capabilities then I'll upgrade into an unbootable state.

Maybe there are some interesting comments raised in this Ubuntu Discourse post

Ok I was impatient so I went ahead with the upgrade after backing up some files to a USB and it turns out it works.
So horray!
